# React Dev Tools Profiler is not Finishing Processing Data Step

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge, react-devtools

I was attempting to use React's Dev Tools Extension to find performance bottlenecks in an application the company I work for is developing. I hit the 'Reload and Profile' button and changed the page of a table rendered on the page. I then hit the 'Stop Profiling' button and it said "Processing data... This should only take a minute.". I left for lunch and came back about 1 hour later and it was still saying the same message. The problem is that I'm not able to see the results of my profiling to determine where the performance bottleneck is because the 'processing data' step doesn't complete.

I tried restarting my computer, changing my browser from Microsoft Edge to Google Chrome to Mozilla firefox with the same results. I searched online for anything relating to this issue but only found articles that were explaning how you can use profiling through the React Dev Tools Extension but not anything mentioning the processing data step not completing.

Comment: Have you figured it out ? @Shawn Peery